# Prove that $x^2-x-1 = F_{12m + 7}$ has no solutions.

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, integers

> Let $\{F_n\} -$ [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number): $F_1=F_2=1, F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}, n\ge2$. Prove that $$x^2-x-1 = F_{12m + 7}$$ has no solutions.
>   $x\in \mathbb N$
>
> #### My work so far:

$$F_{12m+7}\equiv5(\bmod8),$$ then $x\equiv3(\bmod8)$ or $x\equiv6(\bmod8)$

Comment: I suspect that something can be done with the fact that $x^x-x-1$ is the characteristic polynomial of the Fibonacci recursion formula. But I am not at  all sure *what* that something is …

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen But you came up with a demanding question, whether $x^x-x-1=F_{12m+7}$ is possible.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: is it possible that $5q^4-50q^2+61$ is a square, if $q$ is odd and $q\not\in\{1,3,19\}$?

Comment: (I am exploiting that $a$ is a Fibonacci number iff $5a^2\pm 4$ is a square, turning the problem into *show that the following elliptic curve has a finite number of integer points*)

Comment: Anyway, by imposing that $5+4 F_{12m+7}$ is a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{7}$ and $\!\!\pmod{23}$ it follows that $m\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ has to hold.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Hmm? Oh, I see, you are referring to the typo in my “characteristic polynomial”? It should of course be $x^2-x-1$. (No, I still don't know what it could be used for, but then I haven't spent any time thinking about it. It was just a quick off-the-cuff observation.)